# Django UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tags' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models

Why do I face this problem? I am trying to get the tags from the Post table.Post and tags are two tables with Many to Many relation.

in models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

in views

```
def post_details(request,slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    tags = Post.objects.filter(tags) 
    comment = post.comments.all()
    return render (request,'mblog/post_detail.html',{'post': post ,'tags': tags,'comment': comment})
```

Comment: What is `tags = Post.objects.filter(tags) ` supposed to do?

Comment: Also share entire models instead of sharing few fields.

Comment: tags = Post.objects.filter(tags) is intended to return the tags for this specific post(example new,trending)

Comment: you are passing off tags to the filter call before its been defined to have a value.

Comment: You need to initialize the tags variable before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace

```
tags = Post.objects.filter(tags)
```

with simply

```
tags = post.tags
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tags = Post.objects.filter(tags)` makes no sense: you are filtering `Post` objects, not `Tag` objects, and you are using a variable named `tags` before that variable is even assigned. You probably want to use `post.tags.all()`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def post_details(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    tags = post.tags.all()
    comment = post.comments.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'mblog/post_detail.html',
        {'post': post, 'tags': tags, 'comment': comment},
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the tags variable before accessing it.

Try this code:

```
tags = Tag.objects.all()
posts = tags.Post.all()
```